# Convert String or String[] to List with Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a multiple select variable posting to controller. The way multiple select works is that it is passed as a single String if there was only one value selected and as a String[] if more than one values selected. I want to keep processing simple and treat the passed value(s) the same. So the best way I can up with is to convert it to List like so:

```
def selectedValues = params.selectedValues

List valuelist = new ArrayList()

if(selectedValues instanceof String) {
    valuelist.add(selectedValues)
} else {
    valuelist = selectedValues as List
}
```

It works but I am curious if there is a groovier way to do this, maybe with a one liner :).

Of course if I simply do:

```
List valuelist = selectedValues as List
```

It will not work for a single selected value as it will convert it from lets say 24 to [2,4]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use flatten to get that:

```
def toList(value) {
    [value].flatten().findAll { it != null }
}

assert( ["foo"] == toList("foo") )
assert( ["foo", "bar"] == toList(["foo", "bar"]) )
assert( [] == toList([]) )
assert( [] == toList(null) )
```

Or, if you don't want a separate method, you can do it as a one liner:

```
[params.selectedValues].flatten().findAll{ it != null }
```

I'd personally just write two methods and let the type system deal with it for me:

```
def toList(String value) {
    return [value]
}

def toList(value) {
    value ?: []
}

assert( ["foo"] == toList("foo") )
assert( ["foo", "bar"] == toList(["foo", "bar"]) )
assert( [] == toList([]) )
assert( [] == toList(null) )
```

It's more efficient and I think a little more obvious what's going on.

Comment: shorter than .findAll { it != null } is just `- null`, which will remove all null entries from the array.

Answer (score 20):

In the latest grails, just use `params.list('xxx')`.

Comment: This is actually the better solution for that problem as it's the simpler, therefore more elegant. You don't need to mess up your code with 'flatten()' or use method overload and stuff.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
def valueList = []
valueList = valueList + params?.selectedValues
```

**Update:**
A couple other options depending on what you want the null case to be.  As Ted pointed out, the above solution will return [null] when params?.selectedValues is null, which may not be what you want.

```
// if you want null to return []
def valueList = [] + (params?.selectedValues ?: [])
```

or

```
// if you want null to return null
def valueList = params?.selectedValues ? ([] + params?.selectedValues) : null
```

Comment: that doesn't work if selectedValues is null, but that's easily fixed with the if?then:else operator: def valueList = params?.selectedValues ? [] + params?.selectedValues : []

Comment: As written, my solution will return [null], the solution you propose will return [], and the solution Micor proposed will return null for selectedValues == null. You're right though, that may not be the desired behavior if a null value is a possibility.